# getting all c++ operators

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to parse C++ code with ANTLR4 with a parser in Python3. I have a code line below,

```
std::stringstream str;
str << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";
```

I have a visitor function for every `visitShiftexpression`, and inside it I can get the whole line `str << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";`, I want to be able to loop through each of those `<<` and get each of them one by one.

Can anyone please let me know how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest version of C++ grammar and I got std::vector for the operators and by iterating over the std::vector i managed to get what i needed.